# What is the purpose of the new &__cft__[0] and &__tn__ parameters in Facebook post & comment URLs?

Tags: facebook

In Facebook, the timestamp on a comment or post is a URL pointing to that comment or post. You can right-click one of those timestamps and "copy link address" or "copy link location" or similar, to get a link to the comment or post, which can be sent in an email, bookmarked, etc.

However, somewhere around late May, 2020, Facebook changed those URLs. Now when I right-click the timestamp and copy the URL for a facebook comment, there are two additional parameters added to the URL:

&__cft__[0]=...*{a long string of mostly-alphanumeric characters)...*

&__tn__=R]-R

What are they?

(The "tn" suggests something to do with a thumbnail, perhaps?)

The additional parameters don't seem to have any obvious effect. If I remove them, the link still works.

Comment: Did you get your answers? i need that answers too...

Comment: No, Dan, I've never found the answer.
If you find it, please post it here.

Comment: I imagine the C stands for cookie, and T is tracking. You can remove everything after the ampersand and the link still works fine. Also, if you click one of those links, the cft-part is removed when the page loads.